# Python and Selenium Search for Text Outside of Tags

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a selenium script using python that is able to search for a specific text and click on it. Below is an example of the code I'm working with. In this example I'm searching for the string "Next" and clicking on it.

```
<div class="btn-container text-center">
<button id="btnNext" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Next</button>
 </div>
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btnNext']").click()
driver.find_element_by_id('btnNext').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + 'Next' + "')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Next')]").click()
```

But no luck so far. Any suggestions? Thank you for all the help!

Comment: These are actually good and valid tries, what error are you getting? Is this element inside an iframe or not?

Comment: Did you tried using `WebDriverWait` to wait until button present??

Comment: Try once as `WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btnNext'))).click()`..and let me know..:)